# html tabs and links

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs

Hi guys I have bought this template, and I am trying to get a link into a sidebar (under links to tabs)

```
 <ul class="nav2 nav">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#tab1">Seniors - Studies</a>     </li>

            <br><div align="center"><img src="images/seniorbrochure.jpg" width="200" class="foo"><br><a href="pdf.pdf">Download PDF</a><br><br><div class="heading">We Support</div></div></ul>
```

This is a bit of the code, as you see I have a link download PDF to pdf.pdf (just as testing) but whenever I click on it it actually loads a blank tab and doesn't try to go to pdf.pdf at all, I can't put the link outside of the ul tab or else the whole layout gets messed up, is there any way around this?

Comment: First thing I would do is double check that the path to the PDF is correct.

Comment: As @Kris said, you have to check if the path of the pdf is correct. Did you try using an "invisible" iframe and adding link's target attribute pointing to it?

Comment: it isn't correct but why does it matter? if it didn't exist it would show an error page, not a blank tab (within the website)? I have just because you said so put it to a valid link but it still loads a blank tab, im not sure with what you mean about the invisible iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the filepath correct? "your website/folder/pdf.pdf" . Or maybe you could try putting a button in the sidebar to download it - `<input type="button" value="Download PDF" onClick="window.location.href='/folder/pdf.pdf'">`.

Comment: Thanks the button did the work, I imagine I can style this button to make it look like a normale link?

Comment: Great! I think you can make it look like a normal link by using "background:transparent;" in the css.